# How To Use Windows User For SQLCMD?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, sqlcmd, invoke-sqlcmd

**I need to Use Windows User for SQLCMD.**

```
C:\Users\Administrator>sqlcmd -S myserver\myinstance -U mydomain\myuser -P ***
```

This Command Not Correct . How Can I figured This?
Windows Authentication Is OK!
Password is Correct!
Windows User Added To SQL Login.

Comment: Login as `mydomain\myuser` and run `sqlcmd -S myserver\myinstance -E` or invoke sqlcmd with [`RUNAS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runas) to specify alternate credentials.

Comment: If you are specifying a username and password, then you are using SQL Authentication; a trusted connection uses the existing already authenticated account that is currently logged in.

Comment: yes,thanks. i know this but i need to send windows user as sql user in some application that need connection. i want to know specific syntax for use windows user in that app. that app could not use [domain\user] for connect to db.

Comment: If you need to connect as a different user from an application, you need to use impersonation; you cannot pass Windows Credentials like SQL Authentication credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to connect as a different user from an application, you need to use impersonation; **you cannot pass Windows Credentials like SQL Authentication credentials.**